# Removing last node of a linked list - possible wrong implementation?

Tags: c, linked-list

I came across [this](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) site, where removing last node of a linked list is implemented with the following code:

```
int remove_last(node_t * head) {
    int retval = 0;
    /* if there is only one item in the list, remove it */
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        head->val
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return retval;
    }

    node_t * current = head;

    while (current->next->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

My question is simple, isn't this example wrong? I mean it will free the memory of the node only if there is only one node. In any other case it does not really do something, only keeps going to the next node in `while (current->next->next != NULL)` loop. Am I not noticing something?

Comment: It would seem like someone forgot to finish writing the function - there's no `return` statement either...

Comment: You are right : it is wrong.

Comment: `head->val`, `head = NULL;` : no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The method is wrong. Moreover head itself can be equal to NULL so even the first executable statement of the method

```
if (head->next == NULL) {
```

can result in program abend.

And below this statement there is a syntax error

```
if (head->next == NULL) {
    head->val
    free(head);
```

So the code will not be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
int remove_last(node_t * head)
{
    int retval = 0;
    /* if there is only one item in the list, remove it */
    if (head->next == NULL) 
    {
        retval = head->val;
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return retval;
    }
    /*if there are another items */
    else
    {
        node_t * current = head;
        while (current->next->next != NULL) 
            current = current->next;
        retval = current->val;
        free(current->next);
        current->next = NULL;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: This code is better but only partially correct. The return value is inconsistent: In the if block retval is the value of the last node (head), and in the else block retval is the value of the node that becomes the last node (current). also the return statement in the if block is not neccessary and head = NULL has no effect at all.

Comment: That's correct, I prefer to return the list though or nothing.